# How do i dry papaya in oven?

Tags: oven, papaya

I like to use papaya powder in my kitchen. Green papaya doesn't have a long shelf life, so I'd like a method to dry it in my oven and make my own papaya powder.

Comment: I'm flagging this for closing, since it asks for a recipe recommendation. If you want a recipe for dried papaya, there are tons available on the internet.

Comment: She's asking for a cooking method, not a recipe, though.  Most recipes for tried papaya assume that you're going to eat chunks; drying it for powder is different.  Disagree with closing.